# Sand Colored dry wall to birght white

Tags: repainting

I need to repaint a front bedroom.  Did I need to prime the sand colored walls first or may I go ahead and bright bright white over it.

Comment: Do you know if your existing paint is oil or latex based? If not, try rubbing it with acetone (nail polish removers sometimes have acetone -- check the label) and see. If you get paint residue, it's latex. If no residue, it's oil.

Comment: What kind of defects does the old paint have?

Answer (score 1):

No. If the wall is painted it is essentially already primed.

Comment: 100% correct. You do need to ensure the existing surface is properly prepared (dull and clean).